# how does radix in parseInt really work?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how radix calculation really works in parseInt.

I want to build a own formula/function to do exactly the same as parseInt, so that I can put it into another programming language or tell my students in my math class so that they can learn it (not that I would never do it).

I just want to know how it works.

I put together a little fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cy6Bx/

**EDIT** just figure it out by myself here is the result: https://tinker.io/3ca4c

It dose not have all the validation and such that parseInt has, but it dose the basic things to understand whats going on

Comment: Are you asking how to manually convert a decimal number into a number with a different base?

Comment: *"I want to build my own formula .... I put together a little fiddle."* -- I dropped by the fiddle expecting to see your attempt, and all I got was *hocus pocus* :~(

Answer (score 0):

> "I'm wondering how radix calculation really works in parseInt."

In fact, is not rocket science, the most simple `parseInt` implementation (agnostic to the language) would iterate the string (in reverse order) and multiply the `radix` factor by the character numeric value ('0' -> 0, '1' -> 1, ..., 'A' -> 10, ..., 'F' -> 15) raising the radix in every iteration

Something like:

```
value = 0
base = 1
for every character c in numeric_string (iterate in backwards) 
   var d = digitValueOf(c)
   value = value + d * base
   base = base * radix
end for
```